# Arguments against the importance of happiness and possible substitutes

Tags: meaning-of-life, happiness

What arguments are there against the importance of happiness, by which I mean anything from a hedonistic mood or affect, through a world that might create feelings of happiness, and including human flourishing as virtuous welfare.

If it isn't that important, then what is?

Comment: random, but plato suggests that the souls of dead philosophers approach the condition of the gods in blessed eternal contemplation. sounds ok

Comment: Look into Stoics and Schopenhauer, see e.g. [Woods, The semi-satisfied life](https://aeon.co/essays/for-schopenhauer-happiness-is-a-state-of-semi-satisfaction) :"a happy life is not even possible, according to Schopenhauer, because, remember, all life is suffering. Devising systems of morals to act as a guide to a happy life is, as far as Schopenhauer is concerned, a fool’s errand."

Comment: Another option is [existentialism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/existentialism) with "authenticity".

Comment: perhaps if we were to embody our ideals completely then we would cease to represent them to ourselves @Conifold i may not be the worst possible person, but if i were then i would at least be consistent